# Bluetooth low energy - service reads non standard characteristics

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question regarding Android and Bluetooth Low Energy. When I read non standard characteristics of some device like for example blood pressure device I am not sure where in code I should get this data. I have a class for standard characteristics for standard devices but I don't want to mix methods for standard devices with non standard methods. What class would be the best for that? What name would you suggest? Thank you for help and I am nubby to Android please take it into account.

Comment: Do you mean non Spec specified characteristics?  There is nothing stopping you working with them exactly like spec specified characteristics.  Just use the standard API's.  All you need to do is find out the data format form however is responsible for them.  Which of course may be easier said than done.

Comment: It was kind of hard to solve the problem. Someone else found solution just by looking on code from one of the apps. Thanks for help.